# How to add google Navigation using Phonegap and Jquery Mobile

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing phonegap application using JQM and HTMl5. how to add Google Navigation sort of feature in my app which should have geolocation and voice driven features like turn and entering address via voice